# How to get unique rows in a file if 2 or more lines start with same word

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

### inputfile.log

```
HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Session not available
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Session not available 
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Unable to locate element:
HSDA_9_CreateAccounAndBuyDeviceInCheckoutTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_2_BuyMapswithNewUserAtCheckOutTest): Address already in use: connect
HSDA_69_ChangeBillingAddressInNonUSLocaleForAllFieldsTest): Index: 0, Size: 0
```

### output expected

```
HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Session not available 
HSDA_9_CreateAccounAndBuyDeviceInCheckoutTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_2_BuyMapswithNewUserAtCheckOutTest): Address already in use: connect
HSDA_69_ChangeBillingAddressInNonUSLocaleForAllFieldsTest): Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: it looks like you are expecting us to write a script for you

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`, I would:

1. Set field separator to ':'
2. For each row where the saved value of the first field is not equal to the first field:

   - print that entire row
   - save the value of the first field

In other words:

```
awk -F':' ' $1 != first { print; first = $1 } inputfile.log
```

I'd be done in time to curl up with [a good book](http://tinyurl.com/SedAwkBook).

Comment: Guess I need that book more than anything else. :(

Comment: With which part of this are you having difficulty?

Comment: No, it's just that its an excellent solution. +1 cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

I did a "translation" for @Johnsyweb's answer:

```
awk -F':' '($1 in a){next;} !a[$1]++;'  input
```

oh, forgot the test:

```
kent$  echo "HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Session not available
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Session not available 
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Unable to locate element:
HSDA_9_CreateAccounAndBuyDeviceInCheckoutTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_2_BuyMapswithNewUserAtCheckOutTest): Address already in use: connect
HSDA_69_ChangeBillingAddressInNonUSLocaleForAllFieldsTest): Index: 0, Size: 0
"|awk -F':' '($1 in a){next;} !a[$1]++;'

HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Session not available 
HSDA_9_CreateAccounAndBuyDeviceInCheckoutTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_2_BuyMapswithNewUserAtCheckOutTest): Address already in use: connect
HSDA_69_ChangeBillingAddressInNonUSLocaleForAllFieldsTest): Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: Ok you don't have to rub it on my face!! :( Sniff Sniff

Comment: @JaypalSingh I didn't put any thinking, just did a word2Code translation...

Comment: Yea yea … Though, I never stop learning from your answers. +1

Comment: But you have to give me credit. I can make simple things complicated. Isn't it?? :)

Comment: Not an exact translation, I would only store one 'key' at a time.

Comment: @Johnsyweb yep, I noticed it too. a question of Sorted or not.

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
awk -F_ '!a[$2]++{b[NR]=$0}
END{for(NR=1;NR<=length(b);NR++) if(b[NR]!~/^$/) print b[NR]}' filename
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Session not available
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Session not available 
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Unable to locate element:
HSDA_9_CreateAccounAndBuyDeviceInCheckoutTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_2_BuyMapswithNewUserAtCheckOutTest): Address already in use: connect
HSDA_69_ChangeBillingAddressInNonUSLocaleForAllFieldsTest): Index: 0, Size: 0

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F_ '!a[$2]++{b[NR]=$0}END{for (NR=1;NR<=length(b);NR++) if (b[NR]!~/^$/) print b[NR]}' file
HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Session not available 
HSDA_9_CreateAccounAndBuyDeviceInCheckoutTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_2_BuyMapswithNewUserAtCheckOutTest): Address already in use: connect
HSDA_69_ChangeBillingAddressInNonUSLocaleForAllFieldsTest): Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: well short codes don't always mean efficient. but very often not easy to understand. yours is not complicated either. it would be better if don't save whole line in array though, but it makes no difference if the input data is so small as the example.

Comment: I agree. Coz the numbers I am indexing on can repeat for different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed ':a;$!N;/^\([^:]*:\).*\n\1/s/\n.*//;ta;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not very optimized script, it takes two arguments (log file and output file).

```
#!/bin/sh

file=$1
output=$2

while read line; do
    word=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')
    grep "$word" $output > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $line >> $output
    fi
done < $file
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`:

Content of **script.sed**:

```
## Set label 'a'
:a

## While not end of file...
$! {

    ## If pattern space only has one line, read next one.
    /\n/! N

    ## If both lines have same characters until first colon, delete
    ## second one.
    /^\([^:]*\):.*\n\1/ s/\n.*$//

    ## If last substitution command (delete repeated line) go to
    ## label 'a' without reading next input line.
    ta  

    ## We are here because last substitution command failed. It
    ## means that first line is different from second one so 
    ## 'print && delete' first one and save second one to compare in 
    ## next loop.
    P   
    D   
}

## This point should be only at end of file, and default action is 'print' so
## it will print last line left in pattern space.
```

Execution of the script:

```
sed -f script.sed infile
```

And result:

```
HSDA_17_VerifyShippingOrderNoInOrderConfirmationTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_1_BuyVoice): Session not available 
HSDA_9_CreateAccounAndBuyDeviceInCheckoutTest): Timed out after 90 seconds
HSDA_2_BuyMapswithNewUserAtCheckOutTest): Address already in use: connect
HSDA_69_ChangeBillingAddressInNonUSLocaleForAllFieldsTest): Index: 0, Size: 0
```